# API to search Debian packages

Tags: api, debian, debian-packaging

Is there a client/API library that provides search of Debian packages, so I can search programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apt itself](https://sources.debian.org/src/apt/) is built in C++ and provides some libraries for this in [`libapt-pkg6.0`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libapt-pkg6.0)

There are Perl bindings in [`libapt-pkg-perl`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libapt-pkg-perl) and Python ones in [`python-apt`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-apt).

... But the simple and obvious thing is to just use https://packages.debian.org/ and/or run `apt-search` and friends locally (`dctrl` used to be nice, but I haven't checked it out in a long time).